# Cannot pass broker list parameter from Scala to Kafka: Property bootstrap.servers is not valid

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I need to consume messages from the topic of remote Kafka queue using Scala and Spark. By default the port of Kafka on remote machine is set to `7072`, not `9092`. Also, on remote machine there are the following versions installed:

1. Kafka 0.10.1.0
2. Scala 2.11

It means that I should pass the broker list (with the port `7072`) from Scala to remote Kafka, because otherwise it will try to use the default port.

The problem is that according to logs the parameter `bootstrap.servers` cannot be recognized by the remote machine. I also tried to rename this parameter to `metadata.broker.list`, `broker.list` and `listeners`, but all the time the same error appears in logs `Property bootstrap.servers is not valid` and then the port `9092` is used by default (and the messages are obviously not consumed).

In POM file I use the following dependency for Kafka and Spark:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

So, I use Scala 2.10, not 2.11.

This is my Scala code (it works absolutely fine if I use my own Kafka installed in Amazon Cloud where I have EMR machines (there I have the port `9092` used for Kafka)):

```
    val testTopicMap = testTopic.split(",").map((_, kafkaNumThreads.toInt)).toMap

   val kafkaParams = Map[String, String](
      "broker.list" -> "XXX.XX.XXX.XX:7072",
      "zookeeper.connect" -> "XXX.XX.XXX.XX:2181",
      "group.id" -> "test",
      "zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms" -> "10000",
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "smallest")

    val testEvents: DStream[String] =
      KafkaUtils
        .createStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
        ssc,
        kafkaParams,
        testTopicMap,
        StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2
      ).map(_._2)
```

**I was reading [this Documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs) but it looks like everything I did is correct. Should I use some other Kafka client API (other Maven dependency)?**

**UPDATE #1:**

I also tried Direct Stream (without Zookeeper), but it runs me into the error:

```
val testTopicMap = testTopic.split(",").toSet
val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("metadata.broker.list" -> "XXX.XX.XXX.XX:7072,XXX.XX.XXX.XX:7072,XXX.XX.XXX.XX:7072","bootstrap.servers" -> "XXX.XX.XXX.XX:7072,XXX.XX.XXX.XX:7072,XXX.XX.XXX.XX:7072",
                                      "auto.offset.reset" -> "smallest")
val testEvents = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, testTopicMap).map(_._2)

testEvents.print()

17/01/02 12:23:15 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: java.io.EOFException: Received -1 when reading from channel, socket has likely been closed.
java.io.EOFException: Received -1 when reading from channel, socket has likely been closed.
java.io.EOFException: Received -1 when reading from channel, socket has likely been closed.
```

**UPDATE #2:**

I found this related topic. The suggested solution says `Fixed it by setting the property 'advertised.host.name' as instructed by the comments in the kafka configuration (config/server.properties)`. Do I understand correctly that `config/server.properties` **should be changed on the remote machine where Kafka is installed**?

[Kafka : How to connect kafka-console-consumer to fetch remote broker topic content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33584124/kafka-how-to-connect-kafka-console-consumer-to-fetch-remote-broker-topic-conte?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I think I ran into the same issue recently (EOFException) and the reason was a kafka version mismatch.

if i look here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka_2.10/1.6.2 the compile time dependency of the kafka streaming version is 0.8 whereas you use 0.10.

as far as i know 0.9 is already not compatible with 0.8. can you try to setup a local 0.8 or 0.9 broker and try to connect?

Comment: To make tests, I installed Kafka 0.10.1.0-2.11 locally, then I changed the port in the parameter `listeners` in `config/server.properties` to `7072`, and finally I executed my code with the POM mentioned in the question. I was able to get messages without any issue. So, I discarded the versions' compatibility issue. Just to be sure that I explained well myself: I run the Consumers' code on AWS EMR cluster, while Kafka cluster is a different machine outside of AWS.

Comment: I was thinking that it has something to do with `security.protocol`. For instance, if the remote Kafka cluster uses `SSL` protocol, then obviously my connection will fail. The only thing that I misunderstand in this case is why am I able to retrieve messages using `curl` and Kafka-Rest-API (http://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/kafka-rest/docs/api.html#consumers) from terminal (without Scala). Maybe it has something to do with the settings of Confluent API in the remote cluster (i.e. it does not use SSL).